# Can Indian passport holders with UK residency travel to USA without a visa

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, uk-residents

If one has an indian passport with UK residency, does he require a visa to travel to the USA for tourism?

Answer (score 8):

You can not visit the USA without a visa if you are not on the VWP list, regardless of where you reside.

UK aside, even if someone is a permanent resident of [Canada](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/citizens-of-canada-and-bermuda.html) they still need a visa to enter USA if they are not eligible for VWP.

> **Permanent residents (landed immigrants) of Canada** must have a nonimmigrant visa unless the permanent resident is a national of a country that participates in the Visa Waiver Program (VWP), meets the VWP requirements, and is seeking to enter the United States for 90 days or less under that program

Comment: The answer is right. Though on the more positive side you're likely to have an easier time getting a visa if you've already got proven good behaviour and residence in the UK since the US/US share a lot of data and there'll be less suspicion of illegal immigration if you're already free to live in a wealthy country.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need a visa, since India is not one of the countries on the Visa Waiver Program list. 
You can always check if you need a visa by using the IATA travel document check website (or I think it used to be called TIMATIC Web): https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/